# Spark reading from local filesystem on all workers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster and am attempting to create an RDD from files located on each individual worker machine. In the scenario all the files contain different dat. For example

```
machine1: /tmp/data/1.csv
machine2: /tmp/data/2.csv
machine3: /tmp/data/3.csv
machine4: /tmp/data/4.csv
```

I am attempting something like this.

```
Welcome to
   ____              __
  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
 _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
   /_/

Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, May 10 2017 20:04:28)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> file = sc.textFile("file:///tmp/data/*")
>>> file.count()
5
```

Unfortunately the cluster only reads the file from the machine where pyspark is executed from. Is there a way to get the RDD to contain files from all of the machines?

Note: I am not looking to stand up an HDFS cluster, etc. Just interested to see if this is possible.

Comment: You can use NFS instead of HDFS... But sounds like you aren't running slaves on those other machines

Comment: How were the files deployed to the workers ? If you're using something like SparkContext.addFile() you may be able to use SparkFiles to read them

Answer (score -1):

All files should be located to a shared directory let it be HDFS or something else then if you want to use those files in spark you need to add those files in spark like this

```
for files in sharedLocation:
    sc.addPyFile('file_with_full_path')
```

then you can perform any kind of processing on those file